# PhpStorm 8.0.2 always asks to allow incoming network connections

Tags: macos, phpstorm

After updating to PhpStorm 8.0.2 I am asked to allow incoming network connections. I configured this option for the program PhpStorm.app in System Preferences (allow incoming connections), but am still asked. Is there another place that this setting is stored in order to persist?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a workaround from [the above-mentioned bugtracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-129941):

*This is still happening in PhpStorm 8.0.2. "Only non-JB plugin I have is .ignore support. Work-around is to grant self-signed cert via terminal:*

```
sudo codesign --force --deep --sign - /Applications/PhpStorm.app/
```

I myself am very wary about self-signing anything that I haven't personally written; however, this "solution" purportedly works.

Comment: Just an FYI, after running the above command, you will be asked one more time to allow the connection. If you allow it, you won't be asked again.

Comment: This does not appear to be working on OSX Yosemite :(

Comment: Unabbreviated flags need double dashes, not single.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply reinstall the IDEA and the issue will be gone (at least until the next update).

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue - please see [IDEA-129941](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-129941).

Answer (score 0):

```
codesign -s "my codesign" -f /Applications/PhpStorm.app/
```

[self signing osx applications](http://systemterror.com/2012/11/self-signing-osx-applications/)